# How to monitor website status with AWS Lambda and CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have to monitor a website if it works - response looks like following:

{"response": 
  {"time": 1457564305}, 
  "stat": "OK"
}

And need sending mail alert to me if stat is not OK.

Seems this can be done with Lambda using node.js and CloudWatch.

I tried to create Lambda function and execute through CloudWatch but only see the function was triggered.   Seems I need to push some metrics?

I'm newbie to node.js and Lambda (handler, metrics, etc.).
Would anyone share some hints on where I should start with?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning: you can monitor the health of any web site using a [Route 53 Health Check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-types.html) which can have an associated CloudWatch alarm -- no Lambda function required.  The site under test does not need to actually use Route 53, and does not even need to be hosted on AWS.

Comment: Seems Route 53 is for DNS service with health check on servers pointed by DNS records?  It's interesting, while we're exploring serverless options for some of existing tasks running on premises.      Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, that is only one of the use cases.  Route 53 health checks can be used for triggering changes to the responses the Route 53 DNS service generates, but they can also be used for general purpose checks of HTTP, HTTPS, and TCP endpoints, with associated CloudWatch alarms.  Health checks can also optionally measure latency.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will study Route 53 and try it out.

Comment: Monitor using Route 53 is easy to use, although there is only expected string checking for HTTPS health check, while some other checking like checking items in the JSON response are not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "only see the function was triggered".

Yes, you can cause a Lambda function to be invoked on a [schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html). That Lambda function could issue a request to the website and trigger a notification to an SNS topic if it believes the site to be down. You would subscribe (by email address or SMS) to the SNS topic for notifications. Here's [an example](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/aws_lambda_check_website_http_online.html) of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'm studying your example.   Btw, just note some website monitoring using lambda metrics (https://medium.com/@pentacent/serverless-monitoring-of-apps-websites-with-aws-lambda-5431e6713a66) and use CloudWatch rules instead of creating trigger in lambda function.     Just wonder the pros and cons of either way.    Thanks a lot.